# VPS Host that takes a VM Install

Tags: hosting, vps, virtual-machines

Does anyone know of any VPS hosts that will let me install a VM that I have already created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linode](http://www.linode.com) lets you optionally upload a custom image. [Here](http://thegrebs.com/docs/linode_distro.html) are instructions if you care to try.

Comment: Which is of course not a VPS, but a VM

Comment: I'd *love* to know what the objective, bright-line test is between a VPS technology and a VM technology, LapTop006.

Comment: Agreed. LapTop006, what say you?

Answer (score 1):

Having worked for many hosting companies, I would have to say that something like a customer using his own VM image is out of the question for a VPS. Most likely, headaches all around. I certainly don't know offhand of any VPS provider that would allow this.

On the other hand, you might have more luck with something along the lines of [AMI](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=171) and [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).